# Where should styled component styles live in the tree of components?

Tags: css, styled-components

In a styled components environment, suppose I have:

```
<Header>
  <List ...>
    <ListItem ... />
    <ListItem ... />
    <ListItem ... />
  </List>
</Header>
```

And I want to have some styles for ListItem that are only applied when this component is used inside Header.

Should I pass a prop to List, and then this component should pass it to ListItem so I can include a set of styles inside ListItem?

**Or**

Should I style ListItem inside Header, because they are styles that will only be used once and I don't want to get ListItem dirty with all the possibilities that could happen in my whole app. Plus, I don't have access to the rendered ListItem components because they are rendered by List.

Comment: Found a github discussion about it: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1302

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can do without passing down prop here: it can be handled solely with CSS specificity. For example, you can add corresponding class name to list item, which will tell Header styled component selector to apply styles for it like this:

```
const HeaderWithClassNameSpecificity = styled.div`
  .inside-header { // apply this to Header children with className="inside-header"
    background: salmon;
  }
`;
```

and your list item will look like:

```
 <ListItem className="inside-header" />
```

Another way is to style Header children based on their tag name specificity, and your Header will be

```
const HeaderWithTagNameSpecificity = styled.div`
  ul li {  // apply this to Header children which are <li> items inside <ul>
    background: salmon;
  }
`;
```

so you won't need to add className to ListItem providing that it is a "li" item which is a child of "ul".

The choice between these two approaches will depend on your overall app architecture but have in mind that class-based specificity is more appropriate in terms of browser performance (it should be considered when you have many identical tags and rather complex tags selectors in CSS).

Check proof of concept here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wy35njlmyl

Answer (score 1):

`styled-components` provides an in-build way for [referring to other components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components):

```
const Container = styled.div`
  ${Header} {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`;
```

Example:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const styled = styled.default;

const Header = styled.h1`
  color: red;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  ${Header} {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Header>Header</Header>
      <Container>
        <Header>Header inside Container</Header>
      </Container>
    </main>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/3.4.10/styled-components.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```